# How to convert old SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am converting deprecated SQL (*=) to Left Join.  Are the following SQL statements equivalent?  Will performance be improved?

**OLD**

```
SELECT n.name, 
   n.address, 
   e.email, 
   e.title,
   m.car,
   l.type      
  FROM name n, 
   employee e, 
   miscellaneous m,
   lifestyle l      
 WHERE n.id = 3 
 AND n.id = e.id   
 AND n.id *= m.id 
 AND n.id *= l.id;
```

**NEW**

```
SELECT n.name, 
   n.address, 
   e.email, 
   e.title,
   m.car,
   l.type      
  FROM name n, 
   employee e, 
   miscellaneous m,
   lifestyle l
Inner Join empId ON n.id = e.id  
Left Join miscId ON n.id = m.id    
Left Join lifeId ON n.id = l.id;
```

Comment: side note:  why not also "convert" the inner joins so you're not mixing styles?

Comment: Added Inner Join.  Is the New Query equivalent to the Old query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your new query is not correct.

The converted version will be:

```
SELECT n.NAME
    , n.address
    , e.email
    , e.title
    , m.car
    , l.type
FROM NAME n
INNER JOIN employee e ON n.id = e.id
LEFT JOIN miscellaneous m ON n.id = m.id
LEFT JOIN lifestyle l ON n.id = l.id;

WHERE n.id = 3
```

Both queries will perform the same. The first one is just old style.

<sub>*Please "Mark as Answer" if a post has answered the question*</sub>